# Create SQL IN (0, 1) from html form that passes "", 0 or 1

Tags: sql, forms, sql-in

I feel like a loser but would appreciate help with an elementary issue I just can't figure out (properly).  HTML form has select field with:

```
<select name="hp">
    <option hidden value=""> -- select -- </option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

blank, 0 or 1 then passes to PHP as variable $hp

In the SQL query I can't figure out the portion of the WHERE clause to produce table.field IN (0, 1) for the instance when the user doesn't select No or Yes on the form. I've tried about ten variant IFs (e.g., table.field IN (IF($hp='', '0,1', $hp)) and table.field IN (IF($hp='', '(0,1)', $hp))) but not one has worked. Various iterations where $hp is defined as 0 or 1 have worked but I need the third instance where both 0 and 1 records should be retrieved.

I can get it to work if I change the form to:

```
<select name="hp">
    <option hidden value="0,1"> -- select -- </option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

but that feels like a hack when I believe I should be able to get '0', '1' or both (or any other value) via an IF on the SQL side.  Thanks for what feels like SQL 101 that my brain just isn't processing clearly today.

Comment: I don't actually see how this is related to SQL.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks Tim for chiming in.  The question is what is my IF statement so that if neither 0 or 1 are passed from the form both 0, 1 are set as values in the IN () group.  If the form passes 0, table.field IN (0), if the form passes 1, table.field IN (1), if the form passes "", how do I achieve IN (0,1)?

Comment: I think a select box may be the wrong tool for the job here.  You need a multi-select, which allows both 0 and 1 to be selected at the same time (I think).

Comment: I thought about that approach too (which is essentially what I have with my hidden value="0,1" approach).  I was hoping there was another way using an IF.  For my non-numeric fields where there's no user input I can transform the blank ("")  to "%" with an IF.  I figured there would be something similar here (where wildcards aren't an option).  Thanks for the suggestion.  It may be what I end up with.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `CASE` in mysql (see it's doc [MySQL CASE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html))

I create a MySQL table test here to test and some inserts, see bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  hp INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (2, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (3, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (4, 1);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (5, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (6, 1);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (7, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (8, 1);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (9, 1);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (10, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (11, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, hp) VALUES (12, 1);
```

For what I understand you want to return the list of some table when `hp` is `0 or 1`, but when the `hp` filter is not used you want bring all data regardless of the `hp` field. Here is a way to do that, see bellow:

```
SET @hp_from_html = null;

SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE 
 (CASE
    WHEN @hp_from_html is null then true
    ELSE hp = @hp_from_html
  END);
```

You can try this code here: [MySQLFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7qXi81NodZy8wZAidwhqQx/2)

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Cesar for the CASE WHEN suggestion.  I'll take a crack at it in the morning.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Other way: you could build the query in PHP and don't concatenate the `where hp = value` in the query when this value is empty/null/bank.